# I do not understand why the while loop in my program is not working

Tags: arrays, loops, while-loop

Can anyone explain me why this program is not working?
It should print all the numbers, but it doesn't do that.
Why is this happening? Many thanks for any help you can offer.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int doubleCharArray[2][7] = {{1,2,3,4,5,6},{7,8,9,10,11,12}};
    while(i < 2){
        while(j < 7){
            printf("%d ",doubleCharArray[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _it doesn't do that_ And what does it do instead?

Comment: I was trying to print all the numbers from the bidimensional array

Comment: but when I run it ... it prints only the first numbers and a 0

Comment: _it prints only the first numbers_ What are the "first numbers"?

Comment: like this 123456 0

Comment: and I was expectig this output : 123456789 10 11 12

Comment: replace `i++;` with `i++; j = 0;` (reset j)

Comment: Omg...It is working.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Can you please explain me why it is working like that?

Comment: _Can you please explain..._ To loop over the second array you have to start to count from 0 again

Answer (score 0):

You should assign j to 0 after printing each array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int doubleCharArray[2][7] = {{1,2,3,4,5,6},{7,8,9,10,11,12}};
    while(i < 2){

        while(j < 6){/* Replaced 7 to 6  */
            printf("%d ",doubleCharArray[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;/*  Added this, re-assigning j to 0 */ 
        i++; 

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Check the comments in the code.

Comment: ok...now I get it. Thank you very much. You have unlocked my brain :D.

Comment: This answer didn't come from me. Madan has just copied my comment